# How to exclude classes in findbugs gradle plugin without using XML

Tags: gradle, findbugs

I am trying to exclude few classes from findbugs analysis in a gradle setup

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'findbugs' 

....
tasks.withType(FindBugs) {

  def excludeProtobufFiles = 'com/turn/protobufkafka/'
  classes = classes.filter {
    !it.path.contains(excludeProtobufFiles)
  }

  // Generate HTML output for findbugs
  reports {
    xml.enabled = false
    html.enabled = true
  }
}
```

With this change `gradle build` works fine but `gradle check` fails:

```
:findbugsMain FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':findbugsMain'.
> No classes configured for FindBugs analysis.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.58 secs
```

`gradle check` works, however, if I run `gradle build` first. Is there a way to exclude files in gradle for findbugs such that `gradle check` works without failure.

Without the excluded classes both `gradle check` and `gradle build` works without any issues.

Comment: have you tried the `excludes` property of the plugin? https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugs.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugs:excludes

Comment: @leeor I tried  `excludes = [ 'com/turn/protobufkafka/*' ]`. With it both `gradle check` and `gradle build` work fine but it does not exclude the listed files in findbugs report. The full code is available at https://github.com/srangwal/griffin